# "Protocol 'X' can only be used as a generic constraint" when trying to cast self as the protocol X

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to compile this code I get compile time error that's saying:
`Protocol 'KeyboardScrollManagable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

If I remove lines with `//One` and `//Two` comments it will work, **but** then `AbcView` doesn't have to be `Scrollable` anymore. I want to enforce that if you use `KeyboardScrollManagable` on any a `ViewController`'s subclass, it's `View` will need to be `Scrollable`!

```swift
protocol KeyboardScrollManagable: UIViewController  {
    associatedtype View where View: Scrollable //One
    var customView: View { get } //Two

    func doSomething()

}

class ViewController<ViewModel, View: UIView>: UIViewController {

    let viewModel: ViewModel
    let customView: View

    init(view: View, viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.customView = view
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = customView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        (self as? KeyboardScrollManagable)?.doSomething() //ERROR:
        //Protocol 'KeyboardScrollManagable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    }

}

protocol Scrollable: UIView {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView { get }
}


final class AbcView: UIView, Scrollable {
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return scrollView
    }()

    //rest of the impl
}

final class AbcViewController: ViewController<AbcViewModel, AbcView> {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

extension AbcViewController: KeyboardScrollManagable {}
```

I'm stuck! Any ideas? Or am I asking too much from the Swift?

Comment: Where do you make the view controller conform to that protocol?

Comment: @Paulw11 `extension AbcViewController: KeyboardScrollManagable {}`